# Printf in gawk with the correct encoding?

Tags: encoding, unicode, awk, character-encoding, utf-8

I'm wondering: can gawk printf in any format besides ASCII?

Currently, I'm using gawk `match()` to search through some UTF-8 text. When I go ahead and print out the matches gawk finds, it ends up like this:

```
Chapter 9\n\xE2\x80\x9COh, I Get By with a Little Help from My Friends\xE2\x80\x9D: Short-Term Writing Center/Community Collaborations
```

When I really want it to look like this:

```
Chapter 9 “Oh, I Get By with a Little Help from My Friends”: Short-Term Writing Center/Community Collaborations
```

my code:

```bsh
gawk '
    match($0, /^[\|\+-].*"([^"]+)".*#([[:digit:]]+)/, m) {
        print m[2]
    }
' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `gawk` operates in the current locale so it should work in any encodings supported by your system. You can see many references to Unicode and UTF-8 in gawk's manpage

> The POSIX standard requires that awk function in terms of characters, not bytes. Thus in gawk, `length()`, `substr()`, `split()`, `match()` and the other string functions (see section String-Manipulation Functions) all work in terms of characters in the local character set, and not in terms of bytes. (Not all awk implementations do so, though).
>
> [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

If it doesn't work on your system then it's because the current locale's encoding isn't UTF-8. You need to set `LC_ALL` accordingly. Here's a simple example

```
$ echo 'Chapter 9 “Oh, I Get By with a Little Help from My Friends”:' | \
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 gawk '/with/'
Chapter 9 “Oh, I Get By with a Little Help from My Friends”:
```